# mysql ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I try to import a CSV file to mysql. The file containts UTF8 data.
It works well when I use a mysql server 5.5 on a CentOS server, but it fails when I use a mysql server 5.7.19 on a Mac OSX computer. (the first line is ok, but it complains on the second line)

So, it might be a configuration problem of the mysql server on my Mac OSX computer. Any idea?

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE tls203_appln_abstr (
  appln_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  appln_abstract_lg char(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  appln_abstract text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (appln_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci  AVG_ROW_LENGTH=800;

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE "/tmp/tls203_part23_sample.txt"
               INTO TABLE tls203_appln_abstr FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
               OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
               LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '"聚对苯二甲酸乙二醇酯作为锂'
```

You can download the [tls203_part23_sample.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cb7rqjiyxt6wa5u/tls203_part23_sample.txt?dl=0) file.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
```

between the `INTO` and `FIELDS` clauses.

Comment: Hmmm... Seems to work OK on Ubuntu with Percona 5.6.22-71, using your text file as downloaded.  That is I did not copy/paste the text, which could have change the line terminators.  My test was without the added line.  Could there be a CRLF issue in LOAD on MacOSX?

Comment: i don't see why it would be a CRLF issue. this bug reported from 2015 was corrected on mysql 5.7.7, and i am using version 5.7.19.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'm having the same issue using MySQL 8 importing a 20MB CSV file. I get ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'Ra'. I added the line in this answer, but the error is still thrown. Beginning of SQL looks like this: 
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/blahblah/file.csv'
                     INTO TABLE myTable
                     CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
                     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','... etc...

Comment: @AdamFriedman - There should be `CHARACTER SET` clause in the `LOAD DATA`'; it should specify the file's charset (not the column's)