# Mysql Character Set Latin1 and utf8mb4 Load csv Data

Tags: mysql

I have been experiencing trouble with Mysql character set when loading a csv into Mysql.

The csv file contains the separator "," and enclosing character "|"
When I do

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '<pathname>
INTO TABLE <tablename>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(
my column names...
)
```

It gives me the error of
`mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '|HPFT'`

If I add one line `CHARACTER SET latin1` between `INTO TABLE` and `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`, then everything works fine.

However, I want to know why this is happening. Can someone explain to me?

Also, I have multiple tables that do not have `CHARACTER SET latin1`, and they default are using utf8mb4 and work fine. I am concerned about compatibility issues when trying to join those tables together. Would it be an issue?

And there may be new data inserted into the table set to latin1, it may include some non-alphabetic words like Chinese characters. Would setting it to latin1 cause errors in the future?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370517/mysql-error-1300-hy000-invalid-utf8mb4-character-string)

Comment: Load using `binary` charset and use input preprocessing with `CONVERT()` function for to convert your data to needed charset.

Comment: @Akina Why overcomplicating? OP solved the problem in a way according to the documentation and is afraid if there could be other problems in the future.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel This method allows to import the data with almost any incorrectness. And in the most difficult case we can load the whole file as single binary value (using LOAD_FILE) and parse it - sometimes this is the only way to import the data. Of course when more simple methods helps we do not need to apply such methods.

Comment: @AlgoManiac, please focus on one question. Importing data from CSV is one problem - Compatibility between character sets in different tables another one.

Comment: @SMSamnoonAbrar Thanks for your reply. I did try this method too before using latin1. It gave me the same error.